# Scala's Relative Package Imports

Tags: eclipse, scala, import, package

I have a multi-project Scala workspace in eclipse.  I think I'm getting hosed by my lack of understanding of the way Scala imports packages, but after spending more time than I care to admit looking for a solution, I can't figure this one out.  I have recreated the problem in a simple 2 project setup.

Project 1: com.foo.mathematics contains a simple Vector class

Contains one file:

```
package com.foo.mathematics    

class Vector2D(x : Double, y : Double) {



  def length = math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)

}
```

Project 2: com.foo.analysis

```
package com.foo.analysis

import com.foo.mathematics.Vector2D



class Frame(xAxis : Vector2D, yAxis : Vector2D) {



}
```

Eclipse shows an error in the import line, The error message that I get is: Object mathematics is not a member of the package com.foo.

In the outline view, my import statement says this:

```
com.foo.analysis.<error: <none>>.Vector2D
```

I have tried changing the import to:

```
import mathematics.Vector2D

import _root_.com.foo.mathematics.Vector2D
```

neither one works...

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to clean all projects. Build project 1, then in project 2, delete import line, then try typing `import com.fo[CTRL-SPACE]`, does it complete? If it does, then type CTRL-SPACE again, does it offer `mathmatics` and `analysis`?

Comment: I managed to fix it with a heavy-handed _root_ usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `import com.foo.mathmatics.Vector2D` and `import _root_.com.foo.mathmatics.Vector2D` should be fine. Most likely you either haven't added the first project to the build path of the second (see `Build Path` > `Configure Build Path` in the context menu), or need to clean the second project (`Project` > `Build Clean`) after making changes in the first project.

(Also, `mathmatics` looks like a typo for `mathematics`, so double check that you really have the same name in both places.)

Relative package imports don't come into it, they just mean you could write it this way:

```
package com.foo
package analysis
import mathmatics.Vector2D

class Frame(xAxis : Vector2D, yAxis : Vector2D) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had mistyped in my original question (the perils of asking questions at 2:00 AM), but the code was fine.  I managed to resolve the issue in my 'real' project by very deliberately applying _root_ imports to every import in every .scala file in the projects.  After several clean/build cycles I think I have it working.  One other thing that I had to do occasionally was remove the dependent library from my build path and then re-add it.  Not sure why that helped but it did.

Comment: `_root_` shouldn't be needed if you 1) follow the normal reversed URL convention (which you seem to do) and 2) don't have packages called `com`, `org`, etc. nested within other packages. Strange... Do you have the latest Scala IDE (2.0 beta 11)? The last time I had dependency problems like this was quite a few versions ago.

Comment: I do have the latest Scala IDE and version of Eclipse.  The `_root_` thing isn't too bad once you know what you need to do.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have tried adding the project (on the Project tab) and adding the the class folder (on the Libraries tab). Is there another way to add classes from another project that I am missing?